# how to run a.jar file

Tags: java, jar

i have downloaded a school management system v1.0 it was a zip file and when i extracted the file it has some lib file and .jar file so how can i run it i don't know should i install jre to run that file or will it run in wamp server or some other software i am completely lost and haven't found any solution so far if you want the link to the file i can give that but please help me with this software i want to seriously run this application https://sourceforge.net/projects/schoolmanagements/?source=directory

this is the link to file which i am trying to please help me to run this

Comment: If it is not explained as part of the project documentation or in a README file that comes with your download, you probably should ask the project this question. However it is save to say, that you will need a JRE installed.

Comment: not there is no readme  there that's why i don't know how to run it so i should install jre then how should i install it please guide me you guys are the expert i'm just a noob at this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if you have Java/JRE installed.
Open your command line/terminal tool and input:

```
java -version
```

If you don't see version (but see standard for your OS message like "program is not found") - install [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) (select your platform, download and install). 
When Java is ready, open your command line/terminal tool again, and navigate to your un-archived School Management System folder (it is the folder, there SchoolMV0.1.jar resides). And run this:

```
java -jar SchoolMV0.1.jar
```

Good luck!

Comment: i got it running thanks